# flex compile error using dynamic object

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm getting a compile error "1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before colon" on the line of code below starting with `<s:ArrayList source=...` Anyone know where my syntax is wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
<s:DropDownList id="tList" width="100" selectedIndex="0" change="myfunc();" labelField="label">
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:ArrayList source="[{label:'cloud',value:'d'},{label:'rain',value:'a'}]"/>
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing code in an mxml line, you have to put it inside curly brackets (`{` and `}`). So change the line:

```
<s:ArrayList source="[{label:'cloud',value:'d'},{label:'rain',value:'a'}]"/>
```

into:

```
<s:ArrayList source="{[{label:'cloud',value:'d'},{label:'rain',value:'a'}]}"/>
```